# Reverse coding Android apk but music files obtained are not working

Tags: android-studio, mp3, reverse-engineering

I have converted the Android apk file to zip, then opened the assets folder and copied the music files from app, but when I go to play them I get error which says music files not supported. The music file is in MP3 and my music player is running absolutely fine.

The link to apk file is this - https://apkpure.com/prajna-yoga/com.gmanlabs.prajnayoga

The music file link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aH2xqTYS8gqTpMQK5b1ZFDKmdNawIww8/view?usp=sharing

So far looking at the files, I think that the the exoplayer is being used to play this MP3 file. is there any way I can run the MP3 file I got from the assets folder.

Comment: Maybe the makers of the app (is that not you?) were smart enough to encrypt the MP3 files, so that they first need to be decrypted before playback. (In order to stop somebody from stealing their content of course.)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen i am not the developer of the app , but can you help me decrypt this  audio or tell ways to decrypt this MP3 audio .

Comment: No idea, really. And sounds a bit unethical too.